# Unable to retrive data from database using Room and coroutine

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

I am not able to retrieve data.
Is there any way by which we can access our database and we can check what we have inserted so far.
In this code I am trying to insert the latest calculation I did in my calculator with the number of my transaction. Using Coroutines, Room and View Model.

```kotlin
    import android.app.Application
    import androidx.lifecycle.AndroidViewModel
    import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
    import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
    import androidx.navigation.NavController
    import com.kotlin_developer.calculator.database.CalculationDatabaseDao
    import com.kotlin_developer.calculator.database.CalculatorHistory
    import kotlinx.coroutines.*
    import timber.log.Timber

    class CalculatorViewModel(
        val
        database: CalculationDatabaseDao,
        application: Application
    ) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

        var operatorEnabled: Boolean = false
        var firstResult: Double = 0.0
        var operator: Char = ' '
        var ifNumeric: Boolean = true
        var secondResultLenght = 0

        //    First step of coroutines is to create job, this can cancel all the coroutines started by this view model
        private var viewModelJob = Job()

        //    Second step is to create the scope where we want to run our code
        // Scope determines what thread the coroutines will run on, it also needs to know about the job
        private val uiScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + viewModelJob)

    //    private val history = database.getAllCalculation()

        private var _totalTransaction = MutableLiveData<Int>()
        val totalTransaction: LiveData<Int>
            get() = _totalTransaction

        //Getting currentCalculation
        private var _currentCalculation = MutableLiveData<String>()
        val currentCalculation: LiveData<String>
            get() = _currentCalculation

        //Getting current result
        private var _currentResult = MutableLiveData<String>()
        val currentResult: LiveData<String>
            get() = _currentResult

        val navControler = MutableLiveData<NavController>()

        private val _secondResult = MutableLiveData<Double>()
        val secondResult: LiveData<Double>
            get() = _secondResult

        private var _resultTextValue = MutableLiveData<Double>()
        val resultTextValue: LiveData<Double>
            get() = _resultTextValue

        private var _lastHistory = MutableLiveData<CalculatorHistory>()
        val lastHistory: LiveData<CalculatorHistory>
            get() = _lastHistory

        val totalCalculation = mutableListOf<String>()

        init {
            Timber.i("Calculator View Model created")
            _resultTextValue.value = 0.0
            _secondResult.value = 0.0
            _totalTransaction.value = 0
        }

        fun insertData() {
            uiScope.launch {
                val newHistory = CalculatorHistory(
                    totalTransaction.value?.toLong()!!,
                    totalCalculation[totalTransaction.value!! - 1]
                )
                insert(newHistory)
            }
        }

        private suspend fun insert(newHistory: CalculatorHistory) {
            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                database.insert(newHistory)
                Timber.i("Data Inserted")
            }
        }

        internal fun initializeHistory() {
            uiScope.launch {
                _lastHistory.value = getHistoryFromDatabase()
            }
            Timber.i("${lastHistory.value?.transactionNumber} and ${lastHistory.value?.calculation}")
        }

        private suspend fun getHistoryFromDatabase(): CalculatorHistory? {
            return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                var lastCalculation = database.get(1)
                lastCalculation
            }
            Timber.i("${lastHistory.value?.transactionNumber} and ${lastHistory.value?.calculation}")
        }

        fun calculator(operator: Char): Double {
            return when (operator) {
                '+' -> firstResult.plus(secondResult.value ?: 0.0)
                '-' -> firstResult.minus(secondResult.value ?: 0.0)
                '*' -> firstResult.times(secondResult.value ?: 1.0)
                '/' -> firstResult.div(secondResult.value ?: 1.0)
                else -> firstResult.rem(secondResult.value ?: 1.0)
            }
        }

        fun createCalculation() {
            ifNumeric = false
            operatorEnabled = false
            _resultTextValue.value = calculator(operator)

            //This we can use in future to create a list of calculation
            totalCalculation.add(
                totalTransaction.value!!,
                "${currentCalculation.value}=${_resultTextValue.value}"
            )
            _currentResult.value = totalCalculation[totalTransaction.value!!]

            insertData()

            firstResult = _resultTextValue.value ?: 0.0
            _totalTransaction.value = _totalTransaction.value?.plus(1)
            _secondResult.value = 0.0
            secondResultLenght = 0
        }

        fun seprateNumber(number: Double) {
            if (operatorEnabled) {
                if (ifNumeric) {
                    _secondResult.value = number + (secondResult.value?.times(10.0))!!
                } else {
                    _secondResult.value = number
                }
            } else {
                firstResult = number + (firstResult * 10)
            }
        }

        fun clearText() {
            _resultTextValue.value = 0.0
            _currentResult.value = ""
            firstResult = 0.0
            _secondResult.value = 0.0
            secondResultLenght = 0
            operator = ' '
            operatorEnabled = false
            ifNumeric = false
            _currentCalculation.value = ""
        }

        fun ifSeprateNumber(number: Double) {
            seprateNumber(number)
            if (operatorEnabled) {
                secondCalculationText()
            } else {
                _currentCalculation.value = firstResult.toString()
            }
            ifNumeric = true
        }

        fun secondCalculationText() {
            _currentCalculation.value = _currentCalculation.value
                ?.removeRange(
                    _currentCalculation.value!!.length -
                            secondResultLenght, _currentCalculation.value!!.length
                )

            _currentCalculation.value =
                "${_currentCalculation.value}${secondResult.value.toString()}"
            secondResultLenght = secondResult.value.toString().length
            ifNumeric = true
        }

        fun addTextToField() {
            ifNumeric = false
            operatorEnabled = true
            _currentCalculation.value = "${_currentCalculation.value}${operator}"
        }


        override fun onCleared() {
            super.onCleared()
            //This cancels all the coroutines when the view model is getting closed
            viewModelJob.cancel()
            Timber.i("Calculator ViewModel destroyed")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Instead of creating your own scope and job, use `viewModelScope` provided by android. And use `suspend` keyword in DAO interface instead of dispatching to Dispatchers.IO manually, thereby clean the code then edit the question and ask.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing too many things in your ViewModel. If you want to see what the data in your database is, you should have an activity (the View, the activity which creates, updates and handles UI events) that observes your livedata in the viewmodel. Everytime you insert values into your database, regardless of the time it takes, once it's done it will trigger a callback to the observer and you will get the new values. I would start with this, so you can keep track of what you are inserting in your database, and it's the starting point to then using those values.

Would be something like this, from your View/Activity:

```
        yourViewModel.variableYouWant.observe(this, Observer { yourValue ->
           //do something with yourValue 
           })
```